# Integrating $\frac{a^x-b^x}{x}dx$

Tags: integration

I'm having problems solving this integral:$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{a^x-b^x}{x}dx$$
Could this be consider a Frullani integral? so far I tried with an
$x=e^{-t}$ substitution but I'm blocked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is indeed a Frullani integral. Write the integrand as
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{x\ln(a)}-e^{x\ln(b)}}{x}dx$$
Then, using the formula that Frullani provided for integrals of this sort, we have
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{a^x-b^x}{x}dx=\ln\frac{\ln(b)}{\ln(a)}$$
which converges for $a,b$ between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: I know this is kind of a stupid question but I don't understand something here: so my function is e^x but then f(inf) wouldn't be infinity?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. If the function is $e^x$, then the integral diverges, since the integrand won't approach zero. Frullani's integral formula only applies if the integral is convergent.

Comment: @Lola Use Frullani with $f(x)=e^{-x}$. That gets around it. That $f(\infty)-f(0)=-1$ explains why the $\ln b$ is on top.

Comment: got it now thank you very much